# Solving the following trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry

Is there a way of solving the following equation:

$0=2\cos^2\left(x\right)\left(\dfrac{\left(4\sin^3\left(x\right)+2\right)}{2\sqrt{\sin\left(x\right)\left(\sin^3\left(x\right)+2\right)}}-2\sin\left(x\right)\right)-2\sin\left(x\right)\left(\sqrt{\sin\left(x\right)\left(\sin^3\left(x\right)+2\right)}-\sin^2\left(x\right)\right)$

**Edit:**
First I copied the wrong equation, I'm sorry!

Wolfram:
[Link to equation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0%3D2*cos(x)%5E2*((4sin(x)%5E3%2B2)%2F(2*sqrt(sin(x)*(sin(x)%5E3%2B2)))-2*sin(x))-2*sin(x)*(sqrt(sin(x)*(sin(x)%5E3%2B2))-sin(x)%5E2))

Comment: $0 = 2 csc(x) + sin^2(x) (4 cos^2(x) - sin^2(x)) + \sqrt{(4 sin^4(x) + 2 sin(x))} (sin^2(x) - 2 cos(x))$

 In other words, no

Comment: are you sure, that there is no way with trigonometric simplifcications or something, to solve this thing?

Comment: Pretty sure https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0%3Dsin%5E2%20(x)(4%20cos%5E2%20(x)-sin%5E2%E2%81%A1(x))%2B%5Cfrac%7B2%7D%7Bsin%E2%81%A1(x)%7D%20%2B(sin%5E2%20(x)-2cos%E2%81%A1(x))%E2%8B%85%5Csqrt%7B(4%20sin%5E4%E2%81%A1(x)%2B2sin(x)%20)%7D

Comment: i have found only complex solutions

Comment: $x=-2.45024+2k\pi;\;x=-1.90271+2k\pi$ it's the best *Mathematica* can do there are other $10$ complex solution from a $20$th degree equation probably obtained substituting parametric formulas (sin and cos in function of $\tan\frac{x}{2}$)

Comment: I'm sorry, I have copied the wrong equation, now there is the right one... :s